# How to validate model attribute before create

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Pretty basic question here, I need to write a before filter on my Category model, to ensure that the depth never reaches more than 2. Here is what I have so far.

app/models/category.rb

```
before_create :check_depth
  def check_depth
    self.depth = 1 if depth > 2
  end
```

I need it instead of setting depth to 1, just to return a error message, but I can't even get this current setup to work, I get the error

```
undefined method `>' for nil:NilClass
```

So, instead of setting the depth to one like I'm trying to do how would I send an error instead? And any help getting the current function working for informational purposes? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do that.

The most straightforward solution for you:

```
def check_depth
  self.errors.add(:depth, "Issue with depth") if self.value > 2 # this does not support I18n
end
```

The cleanest is using a model validation (at the top of your category.rb, just add):

```
validates :depth, :inclusion => { :in => [0,1,2] }, :on => :create
```

If your validation logic gets more complex, use a custom validator:

```
# lib/validators/depth_validator.rb (you might need to create the directory)
class DepthValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    record.errors.add(attribute, "Issue with #{attribute}") if value > 2 # this could evene support I18n
  end
end
```

Before using this validator, you need to load it e.g. in an initializer

```
# config/initializers/require_custom_validators.rb
require File.join('validators/depth_validator')
```

You need to restart your rails server after that change (and after any change you make in your validator).

Now in your catagory model:

```
validates :depth, :depth => true, :on => :create # the :on => :create is optional
```

The issue will be raised on `@category.save` so you could set your flash notice like so:

```
if @category.save
  # success
else
  # set flash information
end
```

Comment: Whoops, you do not even need a custom filter if your validation logic is not too complex - will update my answer.

Comment: Thank you for all that information I have it working with the most straightforward answer you provided, and am indeed using I18n so I will be using the custom validator. Thanks so much for your effort.

Comment: Great! I18n will also work with the "cleanest" solution above (option 2). You will just need a translation in your locale for [en|de|...].errors.messages.inclusion -- or use one of the example locales here https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/tree/master/rails%2Flocale as a basis. For custom validators, instead of the error text "mytext ..." put a symbol like :depth_not_in_range and have a translation in [locale].activerecord.errors.models.category.attributs.depth.depth_not_in_range

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend the simple and clear approach:

```
# in your Comment.rb
validates_inclusion_of :depth, in: 0..2, message: "should be in the range of 0..2"
```

Answer (score 1):

The error you are getting now is because `depth` is nil. I believe you want to use `self.depth`, like:

```
def check_depth
    self.depth = 1 if self.depth > 2
end
```

I am not really sure what do you mean by sending an error... Sending an error where? You are in a model...

Comment: I guess I was imagining sending an error like :notice or something but I guess you can't do that in the model. Is this a check I should be doing in the controller rather then the model then?

Comment: I believe so... However, you could set an attribute of the object like over_depth = true...

Comment: True I may try that, would I create a before_filter in my controller and have a helper method to do the check then? Or what would be the way to go about that in my controller?

Comment: Yeah, before filter sounds ok from what I understand... If over_depth=true, you can set flash notice or whatever and redirect, or whatever you want :)